# What happens when the Sitecore license got expired?

Tags: licensing, license

(In context of on-prem)

Imagine my SC license got expired, what happens next?

Will all my envs be unavailable or unusable? And is SC company able to postpone this (or vice-versa, block my envs just by pressing a button) remotely?

Answer (score 2):

Afaik Sitecore has Production and Nonproduction license. The production license is not expiring. Usually few months before is expiring you will receive from their sales representative calls or emails to inform you about license is expired.

Non production license or partner license will expired and you will receive a yellow screen when the license expired .

[image]

For the non production environment you can install a module which it shows a Content Editor Warning message or/and sends an email to notify when the Sitecore license is about to expire.

More information about License Expiration module you can find here: https://github.com/KayeeNL/Sitecore.License.Expiration.Module

Comment: Ah yes, the familiar sting of that error page hits good.

Answer (score 0):

While initializing application, Sitecore checks it's license validity. If it is expired, you will get runtime error with error saying `Required License is missing`.

So your environments will be unusable along with CMS site.

To make any change to this, you will have to update lincense.xml file on server. I hardly think it can be handled without connecting to servers.

**Note**: This is a generic error that shows up even when your license path is configured incorrectly. So it is difficult to understand from this error that your license has expired.

Answer (score 0):

If your Sitecore license expires on your environment, it can have significant implications for your website's functionality and availability. Here's what could happen and steps to renew your license:

- If your license expires, you may lose access to the Sitecore Content Management System (CMS), making it impossible to create or modify content until the license is renewed.
- You will see the yellow page on your site related to the license.
- Without an active license, you won't be eligible for technical support from Sitecore, and you won't receive updates or patches.

**Note**: Sitecore typically provides notifications well in advance of license expiration through the Sitecore License Portal or via email to the registered license owner. These notifications serve as reminders to renew the license before it expires.

To renew your Sitecore license:

- Log in to the Sitecore License Portal using your credentials. This portal allows you to manage your licenses, including renewals.
- Follow the instructions provided in the License Portal to renew your license. This typically involves selecting the appropriate renewal option and providing payment information.
- After completing the renewal process and payment, you should receive confirmation of the renewed license. Ensure that the new license file is applied to your production environment.
- Once you receive the renewed license file, upload it to your Sitecore instance. This typically involves replacing the old license file with the new one.
- After updating the license file, verify that your Sitecore instance is functioning correctly and that all features are restored.
- If necessary, communicate with relevant stakeholders, such as your development team or clients, to inform them of the license renewal and any impacts on website functionality during the renewal process.

Hope this helps.